# Android location tracker crashes after a long time

Tags: android, sqlite, tracker, location-services

I have created a location tracking app, which writes to a local SQLite database every time the location is changed.
The app unfortunately crashes after about 7-8 hours while tracking, unfortunately this does not happen when I have connected the device to a debugger, so there is no log which I can attach.
Some more maybe useful information:

- The app crashes before it is waken up from the background(can see that clearly in the tracked data), so I can exclude this bug from other apps
- Tried to write into textfiles instead of the database without any success(Just ran about 3 hours before crashing)
- Changing tracking interval(5s normal 1s fastest interval): Same result app crashes also after 7-8 hours

Here are some code snippets:

*Location change event*

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(location == null){
        location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if(location == null) {
            return;
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    ActivitylogRepo activityRepo = new ActivitylogRepo(this);
    Activitylog activity = new Activitylog();
    activity.activity = "Position";
    activity.timestamp = getDateTime();
    activity.value2 = String.valueOf(currentLatitude);
    activity.value3 = String.valueOf(currentLongitude);
    activityRepo.insert(activity);
}
```

*Database insert command*

```
public int insert(Activitylog activitylog) {

    //Open connection to write data
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Activitylog.KEY_activity, activitylog.activity);
    values.put(Activitylog.KEY_timestamp, activitylog.timestamp);
    values.put(Activitylog.KEY_value1, activitylog.value1);
    values.put(Activitylog.KEY_value2, activitylog.value2);
    values.put(Activitylog.KEY_value3, activitylog.value3);
    values.put(Activitylog.KEY_value4, activitylog.value4);


    // Inserting Row
    long activitylog_id = db.insert(Activitylog.TABLE, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
    return (int) activitylog_id;
}
```

*Initializing service*

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(20 * 1000)        // 20s in ms
            .setFastestInterval(5 * 1000); // 5s in ms
```

Comment: can you please post Logs for Crash ?

Comment: As I have mentioned above the bug never appears while using debugger, I have forgot to add that it also does not happen while connected to Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have something that will help you to catch your crash report even when you're not attached to the debugger - thus helping you to get to the root of the problem! I've posted this as an answer so I can format it nicely.

The class below will handle uncaught exceptions, packing them up into an email and placing a notification on your phone (you can adjust this to whatever you need)

```
public class UncaughtExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private Context mContext;

    private java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler mDefaultUEH;

    public UncaughtExceptionHandler(Context context, java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH) {
        mContext = context;
        mDefaultUEH = defaultUEH;
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {

        // Make error into something more readable
        String timestamp = android.text.format.DateFormat.getLongDateFormat(mContext).format(
                new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        final Writer result = new StringWriter();
        final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(result);
        ex.printStackTrace(printWriter);
        String stacktrace = result.toString();
        printWriter.close();

        // Create email intent for error
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("text/html");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "email address");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Crash Report " + timestamp);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, stacktrace);

        // Make into pending intent for notifcation

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0,
                Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send report with.."), 
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // here create a notification for the user
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setContentTitle("Crash Caught");
        builder.setContentText("Send to Developer");
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);

        // Finally display the notification!
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1337, builder.build());

        // re-throw critical exception further to the os (important)
        mDefaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
    }
}
```

Set this up in your Application class like this:

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    /*
     * Set up uncaught exception handler
     */

    java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH =
    Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new
    UncaughtExceptionHandler(this, defaultUEH));

    }

}
```

I don't recommend including this code in your release version! At that point, you can use the Developer Console to get crash reports.

Comment: Thanks for that so far I will try it out, unfortunately it will take the already mentioned approximately 8 hours to get new results.

Comment: I know it's frustrating, but without the crash report you're flying blind! We'll be here tomorrow ;-)

Comment: Sorry, that I haven't update any information, but I really wanted to test everything before I post here again. Your solution definetly helped me to find the solution for my problem. It was just a simple NullPointerException which was thrown on my JSONObject I have created in a background thread. Currently the app is running almost 24h without any issues. So many thanks for your solution it absolutely helped, and will also help me for future development.